# Fill container's remaining vertical space with image while inheriting image's width

Tags: css

I have a fairly specific setup of non-wrapping divs that are aligned next to each other horizontally and are (supposed to) flowing offscreen. Imagine one long row of divs flowing offscreen.

(Later the plan is to use JavaScript to implement some scroll functionality to scroll off-screen parts back on screen).

In each of this divs I have some text on top and an image on the bottom. Of the text on top I cannot know the exact height. The image on the bottom however should fill the remaining vertical space in each div. At the same time the original image aspect ratio should be maintained and the width of the image should determine the width of the containing div.

To clarify: images should **not** be cropped an **not** be squeezed or stretched in any way. They should just be scaled/displayed in a way that the fill the remaining vertical space in the div.

Well, I don't get this to work.

Here is what I currently have:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Some text</p>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Some text</p>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/500">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Some text</p>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/200">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This obviously does not work, as using 100% height on the image makes it to large for its container, scrollbars appear in each div where they should not appear. I tried using flexbox with a `flex-grow: 1;` on the image, but that distorts it, especially if I add some padding to the text above.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trych/k0x5dhwv/30/) demonstrating the issue.

How can I solve this?

(In case this is relevant: we can assume that the text above the image is never wider than the image (as it is only gonna be numbers)).

Comment: If you use Flexbox to grow your images, you can proportionally resize them using `object-fit: cover;` (That should work in all modern browsers, but not IE.)

Comment: Correct me, if I'm wrong, but I think this crops the image (visually) to fit the available container. I need to fill the remaining div space with the uncropped version of the images. I have made another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trych/h0w8znqg/6/) to demonstrate this. Note that the kitten images are cropped now. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do, can you try to explain why the example is not correct?

Comment: The first example is not correct, because there are scrollbars. I don't want that, because I want the image to fill the remaining vertical space of the image perfectly (without hiding parts of it, so I need to scroll down to them). The flex example is not correct, because it only fits the image in the remaining space by cropping some parts from the top and bottom part of the image (as `object-fit: cover` is supposed to do). I need the image to fit into the remaining vertical space *uncropped*. Let me know, it it is still unclear.

Comment: Have you tried `object-fit: contain;`? Does that give you the effect you want?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, it did not have the effect that I want. It leaves some space to the sides of the images, I guess it creates a width for the div that the image would have, it would be shown with 100% height. See this [third jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trych/9nv7hupf/3/). If there is a way to alter this fiddle to let the images have the correct width, I would love to know!

Comment: I've encounter this problem as well when building a slider. Every known possibility did not give the desired effect and gave the same results as you have. I think our best bet is in the future with the Layout API of CSS Houdini to create a display value which creates this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

To get a perfect aspect ratio with different font sizes, you can use `em` instead of `px`.
In this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ormhukax/, I set the line height to 1.2 and used 1.2em in the CSS calc.

Final CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: initial;
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

img {
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 1.2em - 10px);
}
```

---

Take a look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4nw03vrd/2/

This is the CSS I used:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 328px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: initial;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

img {
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 28px);
}
```

The calc() is needed to compensate a minor distortion in the aspect ratio, which is negligible if the image is larger enough than text height, and it is basically the font size + the bottom padding

Comment: This seems to break things if I use a bigger font size, see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trych/xhykL48d/3/). In FF it leaves a gap to the left and in Chrome and Safari it adds a scrollbar and even squeezes the images. However, I think the problem is simply that the line height is larger than the font-size. So, if I set the line-height to be identically, it seems to work in all browsers, see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trych/xhykL48d/4/). I don't really like that I need to hard code values into `calc`, but this is the best solution so far.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for now and if by the end of the bounty no one has posted an answer that skips the `calc`, I mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: You don't need to hard code values if you use css pre-processor like SCSS. In order to overcome the different font size, you can use em instead of px. I set the line height to 1.2 and then used 1.2em in the calc. this gave perfect ratio for different font sizes (note that font size move to the slide). if you have padding you should add it to calc as well. check out [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ormhukax/)

Comment: Thank you Kfir, that's exactly what I ended up doing. I always prefer solutions without hardcoded values, but in this case, it seems like it's not possible. I will mark your answer as accepted now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that does not require using calc() on the image height.

I have wrapped the images in a div to ensure that flex does not skew their aspect ratio. The vertical alignment of the paragraphs can be controlled with the "align-self" property.

JS Fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/byronj/r42dx90g/31/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.slide div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}


p {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc placerat tristique pharetra. Nullam mollis et metus sit amet dictum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla imperdiet egestas mauris. </p>
      <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>laoreet nec urna. Donec nisl lectus, varius in aliquet eget, dapibus sit amet nibh. Maecenas blandit ipsum eros, a convallis magna varius a.</p>
      <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/300">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <p>Some text</p>
      <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This breaks the layout for images of different height. Sorry, I guess this is partly my own fault, I chose stupid example images that have all the same height. :/ I need to be more careful next time. So the actual scenario has always only one line of text (one number) and below an image that needs to be scaled to the same height as all the other images (the actual remaining height of the slide container.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understood what you are trying to achieve, maybe a sketch can help.

However, if i got you well, try using a `background-image` instead of an `img` tag.

Here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/umf9eh03/

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <p>Some text and longer text as it goes and yet it is even longer</p>
            <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300')"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/600/500')"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/600/200')"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #slider {
        height: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 0;
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .slide {
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 15px;
        background-color: pink;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slide .img-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .slide p {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: In your setup the images are cropped to the right edge of the text on top. However, images should stay uncropped.

Comment: if you know the upper text will not need a line break, then set a height to it, say `30px` and use `height: calc(100% - 30px)` https://jsfiddle.net/upm1ega4/

Comment: Yes, that's what was suggested in another answer and is currently the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I Understand your issue.

Add following css and see if that works :)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  height:10%;
  padding:5px;
}

img {
  height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: In my example the problem is that the image does not fit exactly into the vertical space. This results in the scroll, yes. However, when I turn off the scrollbar via `.slide{overlflow: hidden}` then the images are cropped at the bottom, which they should not be. Instead they should be displayed in a smaller size, so they fill exactly the space between the bottom of the p and the bottom of the slide div. This all needs to happen without distorting (or cropping) the image, so the image needs to be displayed in a scaled way.

Answer (score -1):

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/oz9byj2q/) is a working fiddle.
The margin between the *.slide*-elements can be modified.
Try to play with the value of **padding-top** property of *img*.
You can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp) how to make images scales to fit the allocated area.
I used CSS Flexbox to layout the *.slider* and the *.slide*.

Here is my final code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*height: 100%;   */
  /* margin: auto;*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
}

..

img {
  padding-top: 5%; 
  object-fit: contain; /* also try `contain` and `fill` */  
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198724/discussion-on-answer-by-meziane-fill-containers-remaining-vertical-space-with-i).